# Why sharedFlow collect won't execute this line?

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow, kotlin-sharedflow

I define a sharedFlow in MainViewModel like

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModel{
    val _sharedFlow: MutableSharedFlow()
    val sharedFlow = _sharedFlow.asSharedFlow()
}
```

Then I have a activity

```
lifecycleScope.launch { 
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED){
        viewModel.sharedFlow.collect{
            Log.i("View","Here can be call.")
        }
        Log.i("View","this line will never call.")
    }
}
```

when I click a button to emit , collect will be called , then when I rotate this or back to previous activity , when this activity destroy it should be leave"collect" block then execute

```
Log.i("View","this line will never call")
```

right? but it doesn't ,does anyone knows why ? thanks

Comment: Why do you expect it to go to the mentioned line? Why cancellation of a coroutine would affect `collect()` only, but would still execute the coroutine further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SharedFlow` is a **hot** stream of data, which is collected infinitely until subscriber is cancelled. This usually happens when the scope in which the coroutine is running is cancelled. When `Activity` is destroyed, the corresponding `lifecycleScope` and all launched coroutine are cancelled, item collection and emission are also cancelled. When coroutine is canceled it doesn't mean that the code after `collect` will be executed, but wise versa - the code after `collect` will not be executed due to cancellation of the coroutine.

So basically the line

```
Log.i("View","this line will never call")
```

will never be executed unless the collected `Flow` is cold(finite).

You can launch a separate coroutine to collect the flow, then the line, which prints the log, will be executed:

```
lifecycleScope.launch {
    repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
        launch {
            viewModel.sharedFlow.collect{
                Log.i("View","Here can be call.")
            }
        }
        Log.i("View","this line will never call.")
    }
}
```